# when im trying to add questions in the Question model with choices from Choice model it is showing all the choices from previous additions ,

Tags: python, django

when im trying to add questions in the Question model with choices from Choice model it is showing all the choices from previous additions ,but i want different choices for each(in the admin panel)

here is my models.py code..

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Assignment(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class GradedAssingnment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True , null=True)
    grade = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.username
class Choice(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.title
class Question(models.Model):
   question = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

   choice = models.ManyToManyField(Choice,related_name="hoice")
   answer = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='answer')
   assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment,on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name='questions')
   order = models.SmallIntegerField()
   def __str__(self):
       return self.question
```

Comment: *the problem is in the admin panel

Comment: By using manytomany field you are stating that one question can have many choices which is try but a choice cannot have many question. Choices are fixed to one question. So user ForeginKey relation  so that you can get those choices related to the question only.

Comment: can you give me the example code,it will be very helpfull..

Comment: you could get the question model in choice model like question = models.ForeignKey(Question) and remove the manytomany field in question model. This way you can assign each choices to the respected question you want but this wont be a good way to do it. Try researching on django formset from django doc.